# audio.Play() not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the a script called Timer.cs. This script is connected to some GUI Text, which displays the amount of time remaining in the game.

Also attached to this script is an Audio Source with my desired sound selected. When the clock reaches zero, the text changes to say "GAME OVER!" and the character controls lock up; however, the sound does not play.

All other instances of audio.Play() in my scene are working fine, and when I set the Audio Source to "Play On Awake", it plays without a problem. What could be the problem?

```
Using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour {


    public float timer = 300; // set duration time in seconds in the Inspector
    public static int sound = 1;
    public static int go = 1;
    bool  isFinishedLevel = false; // while this is false, timer counts down

    void  Start(){
       PlayerController.speed = 8;
       PlayerController.jumpHeight = 12;
    }

    void  Update (){
       if (!isFinishedLevel) // has the level been completed
       {
         timer -= Time.deltaTime; // I need timer which from a particular time goes to zero
       } 

       if (timer > 0)
       {
         guiText.text = timer.ToString();
       } 
       else 
       {
         guiText.text = "GAME OVER!"; // when it goes to the end-0,game ends (shows  time text   over...) 

         audio.Play();

         int getspeed = PlayerController.speed;
         PlayerController.speed = 0;

         int getjumpHeight =  PlayerController.jumpHeight;
         PlayerController.jumpHeight = 0;
       }
       if (Input.GetKeyDown("r")) // And then i can restart game: pressing restart.
       { 
         Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel); // reload the same level
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you are calling it as part of your Update routine, I'd have to guess that the problem is you calling it repeatedly. I.e. you're calling it every frame as long as `timer <= 0`.

You shouldn't call `Play()` more than once. Or at least not again while it is playing. A simple fix would be something along the lines of

```
if(!audio.isPlaying)
{
    audio.Play();
}
```

See if that solves your problem, and then you can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I had error using audio.Play(); and used following it fixed the error for me
`GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();`